# Proximity Sensor Nexus S

Tags: sensor, android

Can someone tell me how the proximity sensor on the Nexus S works or what it is?

Comment: This should apply to most touch-screen phones as well.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect it consists of an IR LED, and an IR phototransistor. When the IR LED's light reflects off your face, it is received by the phototransistor, which either generates an analog or digital (threshold-based) output.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the market and download a program called Elixir ("Phone Explorer" also does this and there's probably a dozen more).  When you run it go to the sensor tab and tap the triangle next to "Proximity".  The first line should tell you what sensor is being used.  Then you can punch that part number into Google, get the datasheet and know everything about it.
My HTC 3G Slide uses a [CM3602](http://www.capellamicro.com.tw/EN/products_view.php?id=45&mode=16) sensor.

Ok, *almost* everything about it. Capellamicro wants you to register before you can download a datasheet.  Maybe your sensor manufacturer will be a little more generous.

None the less, W5VO seems to be correct in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It detects when the phone is close to your face during a phone call and turns off the screen and the touch functions.

["the proximity sensor turns off the display when your Nexus One is pressed up to your face during a phone call"](http://www.intomobile.com/2010/01/05/nexus-one-unboxing-googles-first-superphone/)